# rust how to collapse if let - clippy suggestion

Tags: if-statement, rust, rust-clippy

I run `cargo clippy` to get some feedback on my code and clippy told me that I can somehow collapse a if let.
Here is the exact "warning":

```
warning: this `if let` can be collapsed into the outer `if let`
   --> src\main.rs:107:21
    |
107 | /                     if let Move::Normal { piece, from, to } = turn {
108 | |                         if i8::abs(from.1 - to.1) == 2 && piece.getColor() != *color && to.0 == x {
109 | |                             let offsetX = x - to.0;
110 | |
...   |
116 | |                         }
117 | |                     }
    | |_____________________^
```

I thought I could maybe just append the inner if using `&&` but then i get a warning ( `` `let` expressions in this position are experimental ``, I am using rust version `1.57.0`, not nightly).

Any idea what clippy wants me to do?

Edit:
the outer if let is itself again inside another if let:
`if let Some(turn) = board.getLastMove() {`

And it seems you can indeed combine them like so:
`if let Some(Move::Normal { piece, from, to }) = board.getLastMove() {`

In my opinion the clippy lint should include the line above as it is otherwise, at least for me, somewhat confusing

Edit 2:
Turns out I just cant read, below the warning listed above was some more information telling me exactly what to do.

```
    = note: `#[warn(clippy::collapsible_match)]` on by default
help: the outer pattern can be modified to include the inner pattern
   --> src\main.rs:126:29
    |
126 |                 if let Some(turn) = board.getLastMove() {
    |                             ^^^^ replace this binding
127 |                     if let Move::Normal { piece, from, to } = turn {
    |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ with this pattern
    = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#collapsible_match
```

Comment: It looks to me clippy suggests you collapse the `if let` at line 107 into a higher lever `if let` instead of the `if` at line 108 into `if let` at line 107. Is there another level of `if let`?

Comment: Could you make a [MRE] ?

Comment: @Joe_Jingyu Thank you for pointing out that the line above might be relevant, I only focused on the lines shown in the output

Comment: Please try merging the two `if let` statements into one: `if let Some(Move::Normal { piece, from, to }) = board.getLastMove()` .

Comment: Minimal example here looks like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5c7f964314fd2414c6063877c691afed In this case, however, clippy shows the `help` message with exact suggestion. If there's no such message in your case, please show your reproduction.

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
if let Some(Move::Normal { piece, from, to }) = board.getLastMove() {
}
```